# Updating rows in database using Django RESTAPI and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to make it so that I can POST and update database rows from my angularJS app but I seem to be having trouble adding new entries to my database.

Things are posted *without error* but when I go and check the database then all added data is "None".

I have written this method to save Notes with a corresponding Lecture ID, where Lecture is an attribute of Notes.

```
saveNotes: function(notes, lecture_id, callback) {
      $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: apiRoute + 'notes/',
        data: {
          "notes": notes,
          "lecture_id": lecture_id
        }
      }).success(callback);
    }
```

I have written these views:

```
class LectureViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = LectureSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        course_id = self.request.query_params.get('course',False)
        if course_id:
            lectures = Lecture.objects.filter(course=course_id)
        else:
            lectures = Lecture.objects.all()
        return lectures


class NotesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Notes.objects.all()
    serializer_class = NotesSerializer
```

And these serializers:

```
class LectureSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Lecture
        fields = ('id', 'lecture_no', 'title', 'youtubeLink', 'course', 'keywords')

class NotesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    lecture = LectureSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Notes
        fields = ('id', 'notes', 'lecture')
```

Can anyone spot the error that is causing this addition of "None" values? Also, is there a way to make these fields update instead of post new ones?

Thanks!

Included models:

```
class Lecture(models.Model):
    lecture_no = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True, null=True)
    youtubeLink = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True, null=True)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, null=True)
    keywords = models.TextField(max_length=300, null=True)
    #Could add Next Rerun Date & Time

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Notes(models.Model):
    notes = models.TextField(null=True)
    lecture = models.ForeignKey(Lecture, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.notes)
```

Comment: So things are actually getting posted to the DB, it's just that it's none. correct? Are you sure the data is getting sent? What's the request/response in your console?

Comment: @onyeka Ahh, apologies. It seems that nothing is being posted at all anymore and I am simply receiving "500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)". Any help would be greatly appreciated..

Comment: Can you share the models..?

Comment: @KavirajKanagaraj Absolutely! I've edited them into the post now.

Comment: Can you provide more details about that internal server error?

Comment: @KavirajKanagaraj It is an internal error when posting to "http://127.0.0.1:8000/student/api/notes/?lecture=1" however when I access it through my browser the content on that page loads up fine.

Comment: Try to put the response of that request. Which will be stack trace from backend. You can get that from network section of browser dev tool .

Comment: Ahh I see - 

"RuntimeError at /student/api/notes
@KavirajKanagaraj You called this URL via POST, but the URL doesn't end in a slash and you have APPEND_SLASH set. Django can't redirect to the slash URL while maintaining POST data. Change your form to point to 127.0.0.1:8000/student/api/notes/ (note the trailing slash), or set APPEND_SLASH=False in your Django settings."

Comment: Make sure POST URL ends with slash.. BTW.. From the URL u posted why u need to pass query parameter in POST request..?

Comment: @KavirajKanagaraj Sorry, which part do you mean?

Comment: I mean why you need to pass lecture=1 in the URL while you are making POST request? Just try posting to the 127.0.0.1:8000/student/api/notes/

Comment: @KavirajKanagaraj Ahh, it's to get just the notes of a specific lecture

Comment: Then why you need to make post request to get the list.. I think you confused with type of request.. U usually need to make a post request to create some item not to get list of items.. Use get request for that..

Comment: @KavirajKanagaraj I can already get the list though, I am trying to POST new notes for a lecture. Or update notes for a lecture.

Comment: @KavirajKanagaraj Do I need to write a POST or UPDATE method for that?

Comment: Then u need to make post  request to 127.0.0.1:8000/student/api/notes/  and  update request to 127.0.0.1:8000/student/api/notes/<pk>/ and don't make post or put to 127.0.0.1:8000/student/api/notes/?lecture=1

Comment: @KavirajKanagaraj Can you perhaps show me some sample code that I could use to do this? Does this work in the same way for "updating" instead of posting?

Comment: Ok. I assume you need to create and update Note instance.

lets say you have Note  endpoints like below

/api/notes/
/api/notes/<pk>

Creating note instance:
send POST request with following data to /api/notes/

{
'lecture': 1,
'notes': 'some notes'
}

Lets say above request created notes instance with pk=3

Updating note instance that is created above:
send PUT or PATCH request with following data to /api/notes/3/

{
'lecture': 1,
'notes': 'updated notes'
}

NOTE: here lecture: 1 is lecture pk

Comment: @KavirajKanagaraj I think I understand what you mean. However, the POST request using those parameters doesn't seem to work. How should I update views to allow this?

Comment: @KavirajKanagaraj I've made a new post that I think might explain the issue more clearly. Thanks!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34568799/how-to-post-and-update-using-django